# Any way to pass parameters to functions in a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Example:

```
std::thread t1(function(8, 9));
```

This doesn't work for me. Perhaps there's a way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `std::thread t1(function, 8, 9)`

Comment: Realize that if this passed the parameters, there would be no logical way to pass in the result of calling a function.

Comment: Easiest way to see this is by choosing a more descriptive name: `std::thread t1(LoadScript("foo.script"));` versus `std::thread t1(LoadScript, "foo.script");` - do you want the thread to run the script, or do you want the thread to just load the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::thread t1 (function (8, 9));
```

In the above snippet we would initialize `t1` with the *returned value* of `function(8,9)` which, as you have stated, isn't what you are looking for.

---

Instead you can make use of the [constructor of `std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) defined to take a callable object as its first parameter, and than the parameter(s) that should be passed to it when invoking it.

```
std::thread t1 (function, 8, 9);
```

---

See this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void func (int a, float b) {
  std::cout << "a: " << a << "\n";
  std::cout << "b: " << b << "\n";
}

int main () {
  std::thread t1 (func, 123, 3.14f);

  t1.join ();
}
```

```
a: 123
b: 3.14
```